# Access environmental variables in dozer mapping

Tags: dozer

I want to access my environment variables in dozer mapping file. It there a way? I looked the official documentation and they listed usage of variables. But they are not the environmental variable. Also is there a way to access the .property file values in dozer mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a class factory and create a new instance of the class and pass in the needed environment variables. See the documentation. http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custombeanfactories.html

```
public class EnvironmentSetterBeanFactory implements BeanFactory {

public Object createBean(Object source, Class<?> sourceClass, String targetBeanId) {

try {
    Class<?> targetClass;
    targetClass = Class.forName(targetBeanId);
    Object instance = targetClass.newInstance()
    if (instance instanceof YourClass) {
        YourClass yourClass = (YourClass) idSource;
        yourClass.setThatVar(System.getenv("myenvvar"));            
    }
    return instance;
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

}